# Show varying slopes indicator in modelsummary for fixest estimation

Tags: r, modelsummary, fixest

The `fixest` package lets the user specify varying slopes using the `fe1[x2]` syntax. A varying slope indicator is then printed at the bottom of `fixest::etable()`. However, I was unable to find the term for the varying slope fixed-effects using `modelsummary::get_gof()`: only the "classic" fixed-effects appear.

Is there a way to programmatically extract and display varying slope indicators from `fixest` in the GoF section of a `modelsummary` table?

```r
library(fixest)
library(modelsummary)

base = iris
names(base) = c("y", paste0("x", 1:3), "fe1")
base$fe2 = rep(letters[1:5], 30)

est_vs = feols(y ~ x1 | csw(fe1, fe1[x2]), base)
est_vs
#> Standard-errors: Clustered (fe1) 
#> Fixed-effects: fe1
#>    Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
#> x1 0.803561   0.071397 11.2548 0.0078023 ** 
#> ---
#> Fixed-effects: fe1 + fe1[x2]
#>    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|) 
#> x1 0.450006   0.156731  2.8712  0.10292

est_vs |> etable()
#>                          est_vs.1        est_vs.2
#> Dependent Var.:                 y               y
#>                                                  
#> x1              0.8036** (0.0714) 0.4500 (0.1567)
#> Fixed-Effects:  ----------------- ---------------
#> fe1                           Yes             Yes
#> Varying Slopes: ----------------- ---------------
#> x2 (fe1)                       No             Yes
#> _______________ _________________ _______________
#> S.E.: Clustered           by: fe1         by: fe1
#> Observations                  150             150
#> R2                        0.72591         0.86900
#> Within R2                 0.28115         0.17894
#> ---
#> Signif. codes: 0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

modelsummary(est_vs)
```

|  | fixef: fe1 | fixef: fe1 + fe1[x2] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | 0.804 | 0.450 |
|  | (0.071) | (0.157) |
| :————— | ———–: | ———————: |
| Num.Obs. | 150 | 150 |
| R2 | 0.726 | 0.869 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.720 | 0.864 |
| R2 Within | 0.281 | 0.179 |
| R2 Within Adj. | 0.276 | 0.173 |
| AIC | 181.9 | 77.2 |
| BIC | 194.0 | 98.3 |
| RMSE | 0.43 | 0.30 |
| Std.Errors | by: fe1 | by: fe1 |
| FE: fe1 | X | X |

```r
get_gof(est_vs[[1]])
#>        aic      bic r.squared adj.r.squared r2.within r2.within.adjusted
#> 1 181.9366 193.9791 0.7259066     0.7202746   0.28115          0.2762264
#>        rmse nobs FE: fe1 vcov.type
#> 1 0.4320777  150       X   by: fe1
get_gof(est_vs[[2]])
#>        aic      bic r.squared adj.r.squared r2.within r2.within.adjusted
#> 1 77.19273 98.26718 0.8690027     0.8635063 0.1789439          0.1732022
#>        rmse nobs FE: fe1 vcov.type
#> 1 0.2987058  150       X   by: fe1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>